# How to cover my input group addon in bootstrap 3 with box shadow in css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do is when i click the `inputbox` or `selectbox` the box shadow that i put in my css will cover also the input-group-add-on that feature in bootstrap 3.

My problem is the input-group-add-on don't have the box shadow effect when i click the input box. How do i put a box shadow effect in my input-group-add-on when i click the input box? Can anyone help me with this?

current output:  http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/15/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want some thing like this.

CSS

```
.contact_form input:focus + .input-group-addon{
box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
 .contact_form input:focus { border:none;}
 .contact_form input:focus + .input-group-addon{ box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;}
```